# How can I find what is making my Mac run hotter and causing the fans to run more often?

Tags: temperature, processor

My Macbook Pro's fans are running louder. I've also noticed that the [average internal temperature](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/13524/1758) is significantly higher. (187°F as I write this.) This didn't used to happen unless I was running full-screen video or recording multitrack audio. I've made no other changes to the computer that I can remember.

Recently, I turned on Spaces, and I thought that perhaps leaving these open was running the processor more heavily, creating more heat. But turning Spaces back off didn't help.

How can I see what background processes are running? Is there a way to track this down?

Comment: Have posted a followup question on the Android site: [What happens when you kill the Samsung Kies Wifi Agent?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/19531/1119)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Activity Monitor](http://thenextweb.com/apple/2011/01/15/how-to-use-activity-monitor-to-make-your-mac-faster/) to view all the processes running on your Mac at any time. If you prefer to use the terminal, you can use *[top](http://www.macworld.com/article/143816/2009/11/106top.html)*.

Comment: That did it; the Kies wifi monitor was gobbling up a gigabyte of RAM. I killed the process and the temperature went down to 117°F. Will look into how to remove it permenantly.

Comment: Glad I could help. The wifi monitor might be [loaded at login](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/40444/11791).

Comment: You sure that's the right link?

Comment: It wasn't. It's fixed now. You can skip the first paragraph of the linked answer.

Comment: Thanks for that link; I found [another file](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3286521?start=0&tstart=0) there that's associated with Kies; I disabled that one as well. The Galaxy Tab is an awesome machine, but Samsung's Mac software isn't as good.

Answer (score 1):

## [iStat Pro](http://islayer.com/apps/istatpro/) (free)

...allows you to monitor various stats about the hardware.

You can toggle between top CPU hogging and top RAM hogging processes:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The website does not seem to be active anymore.

Answer (score 1):

While we are talking about system process monitors like Apple Activity Monitor, let me mention that Bresink's free

### [Temperature Monitor](http://bresink.com/osx/TemperatureMonitor.html)

is useful to track all the various heat sensors in your system and to record graphs of readings over time. In conjunction with **Activity Monitor**, ***top*** or **iStat Pro** you can observe the correlation between active processes and CPU core temperatures.